# Download latest file from SharePoint Document Library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Caveat: Cannot use `Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell` Snap-in.

I want create a PowerShell script that will search a SharePoint document library for the most recent file.

https://sharepoint.url.com/site/Your_Site_Name/Sub_Site/SharedDocuments/

I am trying to incorporate the `Get-ChildItem` to search for the latest file.

Here is an example:

```
$fromfile = "https://sharepoint.url.com/site/Your_Site_Name/Sub_Site/SharedDocuments/File_name*"
$tofile   = "c:\temp\temp_file.xlsx"

$latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $fromfile | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$latest.name

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient

$webclient.UseDefaultCredentials = $true

$webclient.DownloadFile($latest.name, $tofile)
```

My problem is that when I run this script, I get the following error:

```
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.
At line:4 char:11
+ $latest = Get-ChildItem -Path $fromfile | Sort-Object LastAccessTime
```

I am unable to use the UNC path on the server (Win 2012) I am using.  I get "add site to 'trusted site' and try again, when I try to utilize 'Open with Explorer'.

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: Have you tried using a UNC file path instead of a web address? For example: `\\sharepoint.url.com\site\your-site-name...`

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar requirement as you, but I started with mapping the SharePoint **UNC path** first. The problem was that it doesn't always find it instantly, so a couple of retries might be needed:

```
$SharePoint  = '\\xxx.domain.net\site\Documents'
$LocalDrive  = 'S:'
$Credentials = Get-Credential


if (!(Test-Path $LocalDrive -PathType Container)) {
    $retrycount = 0; $completed = $false
    while (-not $completed) {
        Try {
            if (!(Test-Path $LocalDrive -PathType Container)) {
                (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive($LocalDrive,$SharePoint,$false,$($Credentials.username),$($Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password))
            }
            $Completed = $true
        }
        Catch {
            if ($retrycount -ge '5') {
                Write-Verbose "Mapping SharePoint drive failed the maximum number of times"
                throw "SharePoint drive mapping failed for '$($SharePoint)': $($Global:Error[0].Exception.Message)"
            } else {
                Write-Verbose "Mapping SharePoint drive failed, retrying in 5 seconds."
                Start-Sleep '5'
                $retrycount++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once the `SharePoint Document Library` is mapped, you can use all the CmdLets you need to filter out the files you're looking for (`Get-ChildItem S:\`, ...).

How can you find the **UNC path**?

By opening your site in the browser, going to `View all site content`, clicking `Documents` and select `Actions` and `Open with Windows Explorer`. The link in the address bar is the link you need.

[image]

Comment: On the server I am running the PowerShell, I get 'Add this web site to your Trusted Sites and try again.' when I try to get the UNC path.  I will add it and I still get the same message.

Comment: Hmm.. We're only trying to map a drive, `Trusted sites` is not needed for this. When you paste the `UNC Path` in the `Run box` (Win+R) and click `Ok` does it open the `Document library` then? If you are on `Win Srv 2012` you need to install `Desktop experience` by running `Install-WindowsFeature Desktop-Experience`. Also make sure that your user `$Credentials` have permissions on the `Document Library`.